# can't strcpy segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault

i get a segmentation fault

so at the top i have typedef char * string;

then i just have a variable called spaces that is set to around 5

```
for(i=0; i<=spaces; i++) {
    sepwords[i] = malloc(3000);
}
```

str is a char array, i am looking for spaces and copying until then

```
while(str[i]!=' ') {


    printf("%d\n", i);
    strcpy(sepwords[i], "hello");
    i++;

}
```

so that actually works

however if I do

```
while(str[i]!=' ') {
    char *temp[100];
    *temp=str[i];


    printf("%d\n", i);
    strcpy(sepwords[i], *temp);
    i++;




}
```

it seg faults in this

i don't think this is because i am using typedef string, because i allocated memory beforehand.

any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINE 256

char *progn;

void usage(void) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s pattern\n", progn);
}
typedef char * string;

int pattern_match(char *pattern, char *str) {






int i=0;
int spaces=0;

while(str[i]!=0) {
    if(str[i]==' ') {
        spaces++;
    }
    i++;
}
string sepwords[spaces];





for(i=0; i<=spaces; i++) {
    sepwords[i] = malloc(3000);
}


i=0;


while(str[i]!=' ') {
    char *temp[100];
    *temp=str[i];


    printf("%d\n", i);
    strcpy(sepwords[i], temp);
    i++;




}









//printf("%d\n", spaces);



//strs[0]="hiya boy";
//printf(strs[1]);





}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char line[MAXLINE];
    char *pattern;
    progn = argv[0];

    if (argc != 2) {
        usage();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    pattern = argv[1];

    while (!feof(stdin) && !ferror(stdin)) {
        if (!fgets(line, sizeof (line), stdin)) {
            break;
        }
        if (pattern_match(pattern, line)) {
            printf("%s", line);
        }
    }
    if (ferror(stdin)) {
        perror(progn);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: On which platform are you ? Try memory debugger tools.

Comment: I think you have not grasped the semantics and probably the syntax of C declarations. A useful trick is to read them starting from the identifier, go right through any brackets, then left through *s and qualifers, so char * temp[100] reads as "temp is an array of 100 pointers to char"

Comment: I'd suggest you explain what it is that you are actually trying to achieve. It's not obvious from the code fragments you posted.

Comment: it's supposed to open a text file and then only print the lines that meet the user input given criteria

but first i want it to seperate each word in the line into its own string.

that's what that loop is doing, going through each letter of the line, and then adding it to the string.


the char* pointer array was an accident, whoops. i had it right in my code

Comment: Just beginning to understand what you intended to do with your code, cause it's not very straightforward. You only have one index (i) for two separate things (index in the input string - str - and in the splitted words list - sepwords). You must have two. Well even 3 if you still want use your code like it is: one for the input pos, one for the current sepwords, one for the position in this word. Then you have to add \0 at the end of the sepwords. It's a good thing to learn how those things work, but you should consider strchr (to find space) or strtok (to do all the job for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two syntax mistakes in your code. Your compiler must have warned you about them:

> *temp=str[i];

temp is char*[100], **temp is equivalent to temp[0] which is a char **. But str[i] is char.
So you're putting a char (single byte) into a char* (address).

> strcpy(sepwords[i], temp);

temp is the address of the full array of 100 char*, so you're copying like a big string until some zero byte is found.

There is also this error:

> string sepwords[spaces];
>
> for(i=0; i<=spaces; i++) {
>
> ```
> sepwords[i] = malloc(3000);
> ```

it's : i < spaces, not i<=spaces because string sepwords[spaces] allocates a "spaces"-length array, from 0 to spaces-1.

Last:
If your input contains no space, there is no end condition to the while(str[i] != ' ')
This is where you get your seg fault (gdb is your friend), because you end up looking after the end of str (past the last \0 byte)

Comment: so how do i get around the strcpy issue?